# turtlebot_fake: can have no objects, correct?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3, robotis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems to me that turtlebot_fake when run with rviz will be operating in a totally open field and there is now way to create a map and/or define objects for it to run into it. Am I seeing that corectly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299200/turtlebot_fake:-can-have-no-objects,-correct?/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi :)

turtlebot3_fake node is to simulate turtlebot3 in Rviz.
As you mention that it doesn't include any objects. If you want to load objects, you are supposed to make code yourself.
Below tutorial might be help you

http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers:%20Basic%20Shapes

---

Originally posted by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) with karma: 811 on 2018-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1